# Guidelines for using lucene.net in a web service app?

Tags: wcf, iis-7, lucene.net

Just started reading up on Lucene.net and I would like some of my REST based web services to use the powerful searching facilities of Lucene.net

However I came across a link which said that I should create a windows service (with WCF) to do all the lucene searches/indexes etc as IIS recycles the application pool which will cause all sorts of locking issues.

My question is, is this correct? If so, is there another way of resolving this problem without creating a windows service (with WCF)? Also since I have REST based services, would I make a call from these services to the Windows WCF service which would make things slower?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Indexing

During your reading you would have picked up that indexing is done using the `IndexWriter` class.  Lucene will only allow 1 `IndexWriter` instance open at a time.  When using the default locking it creates a lock file in the index directory and prevents any other IndexWriter instances from being created.  For this reason it may be better to implement indexing in a process that you have more control over.

If your indexing process is terminated with extreme prejudice and your `IndexWriter` class does not get closed, the lock on your index folder is maintained and no other instances will be allowed.  Because of this Lucene allows you to lift a lock from an Indexed folder (using `IndexWriter.unlock`)- a dangerous method because if there are two IndexWriters open on the same index it will corrupt the index.  If you have a windows service that is performing the indexing, and it's the only process in your solution that does the indexing (and any updates), you can confidently unlock the indexing folder on startup of the service.  In a web service based environment where you are performing indexing from a web method - controlling and recovering from locking issues becomes problematic.

### Searching

The `IndexSearcher` class is used for the searches.  This in readonly mode can be done from your service based code.  I don't think it's necessary to create a separate set of WCF methods for this purpose.

### Optimization

The index may required to be optimized for performance periodically depending on the volumes.  Once again having the indexing in a separate process you can schedule the optimization nightly, weekly or what ever is required.  Optimization is done by a call to one method.

### Indexing new data

How and when to get the indexing process to index new data.... I don't know what data you're indexing so it's hard to tell.  In my scenario I have WCF methods that are responsible for input data - high volume.  I require the data that has been received to be available for searching as soon as possible.  So,

my Model layer has a notification layer that when new records of the required type have been successfully committed, a simple notification message is inserted into a local queue in MSMQ.

The reason for MSMQ is that the queue is persisted and transactional and that any messages in there are available even after a crash of system reboot - allowing me to never (cough!) lose any messages.

The indexing service takes the notification, build the Lucene `Document` and indexes the data.

The indexing service can also be triggered to do a full re-index by deleting the existing index an crawling the Db.

**EDIT:**

Example architecture:

WCF Service Methods taking on data commiting it to the Model layer.  The Model layer notifies a listening client that an CRUD operation occurred successfully on items.  The listening client posts the notification in a queue.

Windows Service handles Indexing of data, watching the queue for indexing requests.

ASP.Net app provides user interface with search features.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your ideas, absolutely brilliant. I like the event based notification with MSMQ :). However, our data currently is just file names (i.e. think of windows explorer folders where files are given descriptive names which users want to search). So far less volume than in your case. Wrt the windows service, do you have locks in place ? Is this what you mean by " For this reason it may be better to implement indexing in a process that you have more control over?

Comment: Also, having not worked with WCF, you said "I don't think it's necessary to create a separate set of WCF methods for this purpose.", can you elaborate please?

Comment: Regarding Locks:  Not sure what you mean by "locks" but i have a single instance of IndexWriter in my service (remember only one instance allowed ever, across process, machine, network) on the same index folder.  That single instance i allow a couple of worker threads to use for indexing (The IndexWriter class is completely thread safe).  When ever the service starts up i explicitly remove any locks that may still be maintained on the indexing folder because i know that only this service maintains that folder.

Comment: Regarding WFC: what i mean is that you can create you IndexSearch instances inline in your current code.  You can create as many instance of them concurrently against the same Index as it won't lock the index.  If you are planning however to provide the exact same searches to other systems then maybe creating a separate set of searching services may be an idea.

Comment: Locks: What I meant was code protected with using(my_lock){}. From you explanation, I thought you did but then you mention the "index writer" class being thread safe, so do you not use using(my_lock){}?. Why do you have two worker threads?

Comment: Workthreads for throughput.  It depends on your implementation.  One thread may be more than enough in your case - it may infact be enough for my solution!  I'll have to check.  I just originally built it to have more than one workerthread to do the indexing :)

Comment: WCF: Sorry but I am a bit confused here!! Are you saying you have a service for updates (in another process) and web services that directly access search of the index (which do not go to the windows service via WCF)? If so, does thread safe mean thread safety across process boundaries (i.e. web services and the windows service)?

Comment: My searches are done through an ASP.Net MVC 3 application and the searches are done through the MVC code.  For Updates i have a Windows Service.

The IndexSearcher classes are thread safe and do not lock the index folder (in readonly mode).

My WCF services are taking on data and notifying the Indexing Windows Service via MSMQ that there are new items to add or update to the index.

Comment: Thank you so much, this discussion has been very educational.

Comment: Apart from being really clever :), do you know of any links with good examples using lucene (from what you have discussed above)? I have seen links for asp.net mvc apps but they do all the search and indexing from the mvc app (ie. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320219/Lucene-Net-ultra-fast-search-for-MVC-or-WebForms is an excellent article but I am a bit concerned if all the calls are correct (i.e all seem to reference _directory which checks for locks on the directory even for searches).

Comment: I actually read a book to get to the details and applied it to my solution... well still busy reading it actually.  Lucene in Action 2nd Edition by Doug Cutting.  It talks about the Java version and has example code in Java but because Lucene.Net is a straight port to C# (classes and methods are the same) the book is very applicable.  In fact the java docs are mostly applicable to the Lucene.Net as well.

So no i do not of any.  You can join the Lucene.Net user emailing list by emailing "lucene-net-user-subscribe@lucene.apache.org".  There you could ask for reference architecure info!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply disable application pool recycling and host your application/service in IIS.
To disable recycling on config changes, use the disallowRotationOnConfigChange parameter.

You can also split your application in two parts: Index updates and searches.

Handle index updates from a windows service, and have your IIS portion handles searches (readonly). You would do this by having a mechanism that detects index updates, and refresh the `IndexSearchers`. This way, if the performance penalty of using services is a concern for you, it wont impact search time which is the important aspect for the users. With this configuration you can even have a master index update node, and distribute searches across different web servers in a farm. The only downside is you dont have the near real time searching functionality thats built in the `IndexWriter` class.

http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/NearRealtimeSearch

That being said, I've never had performance issues with setups that have the Lucene functions exposed over a WCF service, especially if your running either on the same machine with NetNamedPipe or on a local LAN with NetTcp.